# How to attach FuelUX Spinner to input element?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, spinner, fuelux

I have a FuelUX spinner taken directly from the FuelUX docs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="http://fuelcdn.com/fuelux/2.3/css/fuelux.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://fuelcdn.com/fuelux/2.3/css/fuelux-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://fuelcdn.com/fuelux/2.3/loader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body class="fuelux">
    <div id="MySpinner" class="spinner">
        <input type="text" class="input-mini spinner-input">
        <div class="spinner-buttons btn-group btn-group-vertical">
            <button type="button" class="btn spinner-up">
                <i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn spinner-down">
                <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when the spinner renders in chrome, the spin buttons are detached from the input element. The spin buttons work properly incrementing and decrementing the integer in the input field. Is there anything additional I need to do to get the spin buttons to attach to the input field beside loading the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're just missing the CSS?  You can find the details for everything you need here:

https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/wiki/Using-Fuel-UX

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've updated the code to reflect your suggestions and the spinner still works. The rendering has changed, but it still isn't correct. I'm running Chrome on Mac OSX 10.8.4 Version 29.0.1547.65. In my current version posted above, the spinner renders inside the input element but overruns the border of the input element.

Comment: Well that is strange. I am seeing the same thing in the minimal example (some CSS styles are not being applied correctly) but on the page at http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#spinner it appears as it should.  Someone with better CSS-fu may be able to explain this but you will hopefully find this is not an issue in real-world usage (as opposed to a minimal test).

Comment: FWIW, I tried the same example in firefox and safari on mac. They all render the same - incorrectly. I'd like to use FuelUX but this is a showstopper for us. I'll go back through the usage on github and see if I can spot a difference that would cause the rendering problems. I wish the examples were more succinct so that these things weren't left to chance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class="spinbox" to a div within a class="fuelux" container.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 fuelux">
<div class="spinbox" data-initialize="spinbox" id="mySpinbox">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-mini spinbox-input">
  <div class="spinbox-buttons btn-group btn-group-vertical">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default spinbox-up btn-xs">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span><span class="sr-only">Increase</span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default spinbox-down btn-xs">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span><span class="sr-only">Decrease</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```